# Static Name for the Unintall Registry Key instead of a random GUID (Windows Installer)

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

When installing using InstallShield is there a way to have the products key a fixed name rather than a GUID in the following registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{Random GUID}
```

and for the alternative paths for Current User installs and 32bit OS

Bassically i want something like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\My App
```

Comment: And what if another application calls itself "My App" and does the same thing? The point of using GUIDs is that two independent software developers will not accidentally generate the same value (neither approach deals with *malicious* software trying to install under the same key as an existing piece of software) - and it's not a *random* value - it should be surfaced somewhere in your installer technology, as a property, etc, if you need to use it elsewhere in your installer (not sure on specifics of InstallShield, haven't used it for a long time).

Comment: If i look at the uninstall path on my machine i see a heap of GUIDS, and then a heap of app/company names. Including Adobe Air, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. If it was a Fixed Guid i'd be happy with that. But at the moment after every upgrade it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer's PublishProduct standard action uses the ProductCode property to create this registry key.  If your GUID is changing, this is because you are doing major upgrades and therefore changing your ProductCode with each build.

I can think of ways of suppressing this behavior ( [ARPSYSCOMPONENT property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) but to be honest, it's of little value and only serves to increase the fragility of your installer.   FWIW, just because you see some other big name company do something in an installer ( especially companies that are multiplatform ) doesn't mean it's a good thing to emulate.

BTW, it might help to know *why* you care what an obsecure registry key is named.  Perhaps you are trying to do some automation. If that's the case, it might help to know that Windows Installer has a Win32 and COM automation interface that allows you to query MSI for information about installed products.   There is also a WMI provider but it's quality is exceptionally low.

Comment: Great insight their. Yes i'm trying to find a way to update these values on a regular basis after files have been automatically updated through a different system. If i don't then the windows installer performs a repair when the application is launched. It sounds like i should be using the COM interface you were talking about. can you provide more information on this?

Comment: Start here and take note of the Installer object.  BTW, if you are doing this in .NET there is a better interop library then COM.  Google DTF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367809(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You want to google Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF)  It has a very clean interop library that is similar (but improved) to the way the automation interface classes are organized but in fact are wrappers for the Win32 functions (P/Invoke)  Wrapping the COM automation interfaces from managed code is quite ugly and problematic.

Comment: Excellent that should help a lot.